# App Seems to Capture Random Part of Screen and Tile it

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't know what's going in, but I'm using my Galaxy s3 to test my app, and it looks like it's grabbing a part of the screen and tiling it as the app background and never loads anything past that. [i.imgur.com/xLfnPtZ.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLCi1.png)

The next odd issue and not sure if I even need to try to fix, is that most times I run the app it gives me

> 09-06 13:23:55.127: E/(21368): : Can't open file
>   for reading

but sometimes it doesn't, even if I change literally nothing. I read up on it a bit and someone said to just ignore it as it doesn't seem to actually do anything, and is specific to the Galaxy S3.

Anyway, my main issue at this point is the messed up background and not loading any of the text, buttons, etc.

UpdatePrices.java

```
package com.example.eveminingcalculator;

import com.example.eveminingcalculator.util.SystemUiHider;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 *
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */

public class UpdatePrices extends Activity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
     * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
     */
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

    /**
     * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
     */
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    /**
     * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
     */
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> Adapter) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_prices);

        final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.CalcButtonLayout);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.UpdatePrices);


        // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
        // this activity.
        mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView, HIDER_FLAGS);
        mSystemUiHider.setup();
        mSystemUiHider
                .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    // Cached values.
                    int mControlsHeight;
                    int mShortAnimTime;

                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                    public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                            // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                            // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                            // screen.
                            if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                                mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                            }
                            if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                                mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                        android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                            }
                            controlsView.animate()
                                    .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                    .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                        } else {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                            // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                            // controls.
                            controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                            // Schedule a hide().
                            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                        }
                    }
                });

        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                    mSystemUiHider.toggle();
                } else {
                    mSystemUiHider.show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.

        Spinner ShipSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerShips);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.Ships, R.layout.spinner_layout);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        ShipSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        Spinner TurretSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTurrets);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.Turrets, R.layout.spinner_layout);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        TurretSpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);

        Spinner TurretNumSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTurretNumber);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.NumTurrets, R.layout.spinner_layout);
        adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        TurretNumSpinner.setAdapter(adapter3);

        Spinner UpgradesSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerUpgrades);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter4 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.Upgrades, R.layout.spinner_layout);
        adapter4.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        UpgradesSpinner.setAdapter(adapter4);

        Spinner UpgradesNumSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerUpgradesNum);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter5 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.NumUpgrades, R.layout.spinner_layout);
        adapter5.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        UpgradesNumSpinner.setAdapter(adapter5);

        Spinner ImplantSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerImplant);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter6 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.Implants, R.layout.spinner_layout);
        adapter6.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        ImplantSpinner.setAdapter(adapter6);

        Spinner ShipSkillSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerShipSkill);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter7 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.SkillLevel, R.layout.spinner_layout);
        adapter7.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        ShipSkillSpinner.setAdapter(adapter7);

        Spinner MiningSkillSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMiningSkill);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter8 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.SkillLevel, R.layout.spinner_layout);
        adapter8.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        MiningSkillSpinner.setAdapter(adapter8);

        Spinner AstroSkillSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAstroSkill);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter9 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.SkillLevel, R.layout.spinner_layout);
        adapter9.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        AstroSkillSpinner.setAdapter(adapter9);

        Spinner IceSkillSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerIceHarvSkill);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter10 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.SkillLevel, R.layout.spinner_layout);
        adapter10.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        IceSkillSpinner.setAdapter(adapter10);

        Spinner DeepCoreSkillSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDeepCoreSkill);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter11 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.SkillLevel, R.layout.spinner_layout);
        adapter11.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        DeepCoreSkillSpinner.setAdapter(adapter11);

        findViewById(R.id.buttonCalculateIPH).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
        delayedHide(100);

    }


    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSystemUiHider.hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

layout_update_prices.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/UpdatePrices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#a33333"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".UpdatePrices" >

    <!--
         The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc.
    -->


    <!--
         This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows.
    -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/CalcButtonLayout"
    style="?buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/black_overlay"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonCalculateIPH"
                style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/calc_iph" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textRegionSelect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/region_select"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/RegionSelection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioJita"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioAmarr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioDodixie"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioRens"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioHek"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textRegions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:text="@string/systems"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:text="@string/settings"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textSecLevelSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="@string/ore_sec"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/OreSecLevels"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkHighSec"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/hsec"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkLowSec"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/lsec"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkNullSec"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/nsec"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textShipSkillsSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/ship_setup"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTurret"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textSize="16sp">
            <requestFocus
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textm3ps"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/m3s"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ShipSetupTitles"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textDrones"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/drones"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textShip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="@string/ship"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTurrets"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="@string/turrets"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textUpgrades"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="@string/upgrades"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textImplant"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="@string/implant"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerShips"
            android:layout_width="105dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:entries="@array/Ships"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            tools:listitem="@layout/spinner_layout" />

        <Spinner 
            android:id="@+id/spinnerTurretNumber"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="229dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/spinner_layout" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerTurrets"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="228dp"
            android:entries="@array/Turrets"
            tools:listitem="@layout/spinner_layout" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerUpgradesNum"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="257dp"
            android:entries="@array/NumUpgrades"
            tools:listitem="@layout/spinner_layout" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerUpgrades"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="257dp"
            android:entries="@array/Upgrades"
            tools:listitem="@layout/spinner_layout" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerImplant"
            android:layout_width="105dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="283dp"
            android:entries="@array/Implants"
            tools:listitem="@layout/spinner_layout" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textSkills"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="315dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="@string/skills"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SkillLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="362dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textShipSkill"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ship"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerShipSkill"
                android:layout_width="22dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:entries="@array/SkillLevel"
                tools:listitem="@layout/spinner_layout" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textMiningSkill"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/mining_skill"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerMiningSkill"
                android:layout_width="22dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:entries="@array/SkillLevel"
                tools:listitem="@layout/spinner_layout" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textAstroSkill"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/astro_skill"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerAstroSkill"
                android:layout_width="22dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:entries="@array/SkillLevel"
                tools:listitem="@layout/spinner_layout" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SkillLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="388dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textIceHarvSkill"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/iceharv_skill"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerIceHarvSkill"
                android:layout_width="22dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:entries="@array/SkillLevel"
                tools:listitem="@layout/spinner_layout" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textDeepCoreSkill"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/deepcore_skill"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Spinner 
                android:id="@+id/spinnerDeepCoreSkill"
                android:layout_width="22dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:entries="@array/SkillLevel"
                tools:listitem="@layout/spinner_layout" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLoadAPI"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="334dp"
            android:text="@string/loadapi"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Android Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.eveminingcalculator"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".UpdatePrices"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".APISettings" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphical glitch is because nothing is being drawn in your window. I'd have to assume your FullscreenTheme defines `android:windowBackground="@null"`. However, this isn't the reason none of your views are drawing. You are not implementing `onCreate(Bundle)`, you have some strange `onCreate(Bundle, ArrayAdapter)` that will never be called by the system. Remove that second `ArrayAdapter` parameter (and add a `@Override` annotation above it to ensure you're actually overriding the method).